# How do I check if my variable is one word or two words long

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am doing a discord.js command that interfaces with an API to get weapon stats, the issue is that the weapon name can sometimes be one word long, and sometimes two words long so args[3] or args[3] + args [4]. How could I do this?

My current code:

```js
async function opstat() {
    let OWeaponStats = await API.getWeaponStats(args[1], args[2], 'all');
    const item = OWeaponStats.weapons.find(x => x.weapon === args.slice(3, 4).join(' '));
    const r6wstats = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('e91e63')
        .setTitle(OWeaponStats.username + "'s " + item.weapon + " stats")
        .addFields({
            name: 'Kills',
            value: item.kills
        }, {
            name: 'Deaths',
            value: item.deaths
        }, {
            name: 'KD',
            value: item.kd
        }, {
            name: 'Headshots',
            value: item.headshots
        }, {
            name: 'Headshot Percentage',
            value: item.headshot_percentage
        }, )
    message.channel.send(r6wstats)
}
opstat()
```

Comment: Question isn't clear. Your function looks like it takes 0 parameters, so where is `args` coming from?

Comment: its not clear what you want and what you want to achive

Answer (score 1):

You can always check with javaScript built in functions, let's say perhaps a split() function you can check it out on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it will take a string and split it on it;s empty spaces into an array, next check the length of that array and do what you want to do and loop again and put it back as a string or use [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

hope it would fix your issue :D